# Map with Set value in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, set

I'm having problems when I try to print the value of my `Map`, which is a `Set`. 
I had to implement all the functions of `Map` and `Set` (didn't use the `map` or set libraries), but I'm sure they work as they are supossed to. The printSet function is working.

A brief enumeration of the functions I have:

```
#define SType string
#define VType set

struct setNode {
  SType key;
  setNode* left;
  setNode* right;
  setNode* parent;
};

class set {
 public:
  set();
  bool empty();
  int size();
  setNode* begin();
  setNode* end();
  setNode* next(setNode* x);
  setNode* prev(setNode* x);
  SType key(setNode* x);
  setNode* find(SType k);
  void insert(SType k);
  void erase(SType k);
  void clear();
  void operator=(set& s);
  ~set();

 private:
  int size_;
  setNode* root_;
};

struct mapNode {
  SType key;
  VType value;
  mapNode* left;
  mapNode* right;
  mapNode* parent;
};

class map {
 public:
  map();
  bool empty();
  int size();
  mapNode* begin();
  mapNode* end();
  mapNode* next(mapNode* x);
  mapNode* prev(mapNode* x);
  VType& operator[](SType k);
  SType key(mapNode* x);
  VType value(mapNode* x);
  mapNode* find(SType k);
  void insert(SType k, VType v);
  void erase(SType k);
  void clear();
  void operator=(map& s);
  ~map();

 private:
  int size_;
  mapNode* root_;
};
```

Now the printing functions:

```
void printSet(set& c) {

  for (setNode* i = c.begin(); i != c.end(); i = c.next(i)) {
    cout << c.key(i) << " ";
  }
}

void printMap(map& m){
    for (mapNode* i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); i = m.next(i)) {
    cout<<m.key(i)<<"\t";
    printSet(m.value(i));//error in this line
    cout<<endl;
  }
}
```

I'm getting a `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'set&' from an rvalue of type 'set'` error, but I can't figure out what is wrong...

Comment: Why are you using #define instead of `typedef` or  `using` ?!

Comment: I didn't know I could

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `value(mapNode* x)` returns `VType`  which is a temporary value .
In other hand `void printSet(set& c)` get a variable by refrence .

It means that you are trying to store and accessing a temporary value which is illegal .

change your print functions to this :

```
void printSet(const set& c) 
void printMap(const map& m)
```

And also you can't use none const member of map class in const variable of it so you have to make begin end key next value `const` too :

```
class map {
 public:
  map();
  bool empty()const ;
  int size()const ;
  mapNode* begin()const;
  mapNode* end()const;
  mapNode* next(mapNode* x)const;
  mapNode* prev(mapNode* x)const;
  ...
 }
```